# Vbscript multiple Statements for single Return Statement

Tags: vbscript

I am developing a VBScript like follows

```
Dim a
Set a = New Class1
a("text").doSomething 'Has to execute doSomething in Class1
a("text").anotherSomething 'Has to execute doSoemthing in Class2

class Class1
    Dim b
    Dim c
    public default Function init(str)
          Set b = New Class2
          Set c = New Class3
          'Some more operations to perform
          If **What is the condition can be?** Then
              Set init = c
          Else
              Set init = b
          End If
    End Function
End class

class Class2
    public Function doSomething()
        'Stuff to do something
    End Function
End class
class Class3
    public Function anotherSomething()
        'Stuff to do something
    End Function
End class
```

Here, Object "a" has parameters and this parameter can be same.
So, i can't keep is parameter "=" or "<>"

And, I can't place those functions in Class1.

So, What can be that condition which can decide.

Comment: Polymorphism isn't implemented natively in VBScript, but there are might be some workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to leverage delegators. Basically you need internal objects that are of the type you want to access methods that would be in your parent classes in OOP.

Here is an example:

```
Class ScreenPoint
  '' Properties

  'Ancestor Point2D
  Private P2D
  'Point color
  Private Color
  '----------------------

  '' Methods
  'Constructor - called automatically
  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set P2D = new Point2D
  End Sub
  '----------------------
  'Destructor - called automatically
  Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set P2D = Nothing
  End Sub
  '----------------------
  'A pair of methods to access private property X
  Property Get X
    X = P2D.X
  End Property

  Property Let X(ByVal in_X)
    P2D.X = in_X
  End Property
  '----------------------
  'A pair of methods to access private property Y
  Property Get Y
    Y = P2D.Y
  End Property

  Property Let Y(ByVal in_Y)
    P2D.Y = in_Y
  End Property
  '----------------------
End Class
```

If you are lost, try reading the source article here: http://automation-beyond.com/2008/11/16/oop-vbscript-2/